# REST API Authentication | AppID + AppSecret

Tags: api, rest, authentication, token

I'm currently creating my own REST API. The API provides data that should not be available to everyone, so I thought about securing it with a Token you have to send when making API-calls.

First I thought about using OAuth2 but I only found how to use it the way it is used in e.g. the Facebook API (A popup asking for a users permission.....).

This is not what I want so I developed my own auth mechanism. I have a list of "apps" allowed to use the API. Every app has an AppID to identify it and an AppSecret. Now the Authentication works like this:

1. Client calls `/auth/requestToken?auth_appId=[AppID]`
2. If AppID is valid client gets back a `requestToken`
3. Now the client appends the `AppSecret` to the `requestToken` and hashes the resulting string
4. Client calls `/auth/accessToken?auth_requestToken=[requestToken]&auth_requestAccessToken=[hash]`
5. If `hash` is valid for the sent `requestToken` the API returns an `accessToken` valid for 2 hours
6. API calls can be made by adding the `accessToken` as a get parameter

Now my questions are:

- Is there something like a standard for authenticating a client like this?
- Is there a better approach to do this?
- Any improvements you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there something like a standard for authenticating a client like this?

Yes, your method is quite similar to OAuth 2, as you can see on this schema [here](http://www.bubblecode.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/auth_code_flow.png).
Differences between your solution and OAuth2 are about *the login system*.

> Any improvements you suggest?

In my opinion, your proposal misses a big part : authorization.
I don't see in your post, any part talking about the rights of the user to access resources on the API and it is a problem.I think it is useless to secure API calls if you don't provide any solution to authenticate or authorize the user.

> Is there a better approach to do this?

Use OAuth2, it is a standard, and you can create your own OAuth2 quite simply, and there are a lot of tutorials on the web.

Here an simple example : [creating-a-php-oauth-server](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-php-oauth-server/)

I hope my basic answer will help you :)

Comment: My API is just parses a HTML page and provides the content through a more user friendly json interface. There are no users. I only have client apps (iOS, Android, WP, maybe WebApp) which display the data. For the app I have to use another authorization system because the client wants an integration into their existing system. So it's just all about making the API endpoints only handling request from my apps :)